# swiper js not updating loop not working properly in react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5xxw.png)

(please ignore my English i'm from India)
this above image show when swiper create loop is not working until i manually slide.
here is my swiper code. when i slide then loop show all duplicate slides.

```
function TrendingIGO({ trIGO, loading }) {

const [state, setState] = useState({
    dataISNull: false,
    isLoading: true
})

const [swiperInstance, setswiperInstance] = useState(null)
const swiperSlide = useSwiperSlide();

const [data, setData] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    setState(prev => {
        return {
            ...prev,
            isLoading: loading
        }
    })

    if (!state.isLoading) {

        trIGO.data !== null ? setData(trIGO.data.filter(igo => igo.trending < 6).sort((a, b) => a.trending - b.trending))
            : setState(prev => {
                return {
                    ...prev,
                    dataISNull: !prev.dataISNull
                }
            })

    }

}, [trIGO, loading])

const onSwiperStart = (swiper) => {
    console.log(swiper.activeIndex)
   
    // swiper.slidePrev()
}

return (
    <div className='Trending-IGO title-mrgn'>
        <h1 className='home-title'>TRENDING IGO</h1>
        <div className='ctn-mrgn'>

            {
                state.dataISNull
                    ? state.dataISNull ? <NoData msg={"No Trending IGO"} /> : <div className='trigo-skl-live'><TrIgoSkeleton count={1} /></div>
                    : state.dataISNull ? <NoData msg={"No Trending IGO"} /> :
                        <Swiper
                            className='trending-igo-slider'
                            onSwiper={(swiper => onSwiperStart(swiper))}
                            initialSlide={0}
                            spaceBetween={30}
                            effect={"coverflow"}
                            grabCursor={true}
                            centeredSlides={true}
                            slidesPerView={"auto"}
                            coverflowEffect={{
                                rotate: 0,
                                stretch: 0,
                                depth: 150,
                                modifier: 1,
                                slideShadows: false,
                            }}
                            pagination={false}
                            modules={[EffectCoverflow]}
                            loopedSlides={5}
                            loop={true}
                            breakpoints={{
                                1080: {

                                    spaceBetween: 50,
                                },
                            }}
                        >
                            {
                                data.map((igo, index) => {
                                    return (

                                        <SwiperSlide key={index}  >

                                            <IgoLayout igo={igo} />
                                        </SwiperSlide>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </Swiper>

            }
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

}

> getting data from server and its working fine but loop is not working properly below image show how its look when its work perfectly. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ3HR.png)

Comment: can you please add the expected behavior ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/129zRK2VYyzqRmlJ1pz1ER_2IOWR3rvRF/view?usp=sharing youcan check a video here

Comment: @Vikassoni Did you solve your issue? I am having the same issue as you with very similar code.